# Expected number of children until "at least one boy and one girl."

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

This question is from Blitzstein's *Introduction to Probability* textbook. Here is the text:

> A couple decides to keep having children until they have at least one boy and at least one girl, and then stop. Assume they never have twins, that the “trials” are independent with probability 1/2 of a boy, and that they are fertile enough to keep producing children indefinitely. What is the expected number of children?

I've read through the solution found [here](http://projects.iq.harvard.edu/files/stat110/files/selected_solutions_blitzstein_hwang_probability_2.pdf) (page 29). It reads as follows:

> Let X be the number of children needed, starting with the 2nd child, to obtain
>   one whose gender is not the same as that of the firstborn. Then X − 1 is Geom(1/2), so E(X) = 2. This does not include the firstborn, so the expected total number of children is E(X + 1) = E(X) + 1 = 3.

What does X-1 mean in this case? The number of children needed, starting with the **first** child, to obtain one whose gender is different from that of the firstborn? Why wouldn't its expected value be 2 as well?

Comment: The first child will have one or the other gender, doesn't matter.  After that you are searching for a fixed gender (the opposite of the first) so it's just Geometric after the first child.

Comment: that makes sense. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $E(r)$ the expected number of additional children when $r\in[0..2]$ types have already been realized. Then
$$E(0)=1+E(1),\quad E(1)=1+{1\over2}E(1),\quad E(2)=0\ .$$
Solving this system gives $E(0)=3$.